# How to add panko to chicken without frying the chicken?

Tags: chicken, breadcrumbs

I like to make chicken katsu and curry, but want to avoid eating fried food. Is there another healthier way to prepare the chicken, but that will still work with getting the panko breading to stick on the outside?

Answer (score 6):

You could [oven bake](https://pickledplum.com/baked-chicken-katsu-recipe/) them.

You bread the chicken the same way you do when frying them but instead you put them on a baking sheet; cook and mid-way, gently flip them over.

It is a *little bit* like making Shake'n'Bake chicken.